# Testing MUI-Dialog inside another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have a row on a table that displays a material-ui dialog, this dialog can't be found by both: `waitFor` or `screen.findByTestId`.
I keep getting the following error:

```
Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="question_dialog"]
```

**Disclaimer**: testid is valid and exists

What can I do?